# FiWARE: Detecting when a sensor is not sending data to Orion CB

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-orion, complex-event-processing, fiware-perseo

I'm wondering if there is any way of detecting that a specific sensor, in a specific path, has stopped sending data to the Orion Context Broker. Then, if that happens, be able to execute some kind of alarm. 
I've been studying FiWARE for some months now, but I really don't know a GE that is able to do this.

Does anybody know how can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Perseo CEP](https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-fe) have a "no signal" rule type that allows to detect the lack of update in Orion attributes. It is open source and you can have a look, although I don't know to which extend this feature is documented.

However, it shouldn't be difficult to develop a system doing so. Just to subscribe to the desired attribute using regular subscriptions at Orion and if you  don't receive any notification in a given time, then it has stopped to send information to Orion.

If you don't want to use subscriptions, your system could query Orion at a regular basic and check the `dateModified` metadata associated to the attribute, i.e. `GET /v2/entities/device1/attrs/measure?metadata=dateModified`. Please have a loook to the [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) section "System/builtin Metadata" about the `dateModified` metadata.

Comment: Thank you @fgalan! I managed to solve this with Perseo's "no signal" feature. It is working like a charm. 
By the way, just as a bonus question, is there any way of triggering an alarm (like an email) when the device is up again? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It is a good idea to have separate questions in separate post in StackOverflow because it is more clear for users. Could you ask it in a new post, please? Use "fiware" label in that question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Orion in itself has no such mechanism implemented. However, it would be fairly easy to implement an application (a context consumer) doing what you are asking for.
That application would subscribe to the updates of the sensor and keep a timestamp, updated in each incoming notification, and also, of course, check for how long time has elapsed since the last (latest) notification and if that time is greater than some threshold, issue some kind of warning/alarm

Comment: Thanks for your help @kzangeli. [Perseo CEP](https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-fe/blob/master/documentation/models.md) "no signal" feature helped me with this.